# Python ValueError : too many values to unpack, solution?

Tags: python, unpack

Im getting this error and i have no idea what it means, i can get the program to print the files from there values but its just a long incoherent  now im trying to get it to print it in an organized manor and thats where the issues arise.

```
import os 
def listfiles (path):
    files = []
    for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(path):
        dir = dirName.replace(path, '')
        for fname in fileList:
            files.append(os.path.join(dir, fname))
    return files

a = input('Enter a primary file path: ')
b = input('Enter a secondary file path: ')

x = listfiles(a)
y = llistfiles(b)

files_only_x = set(x) - set (y)
files_only_y = set(y) - set (x)
```

this next line of code is where python is saying the error is

```
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in files_only_x:
    print ('Directory: %s' % dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
        print ('\%s' % fname)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the data flow:

You call `listfiles()` with a path. It collects all files below that path in a list.

(BTW, IMHO dir = `dirName.replace(path, '')` is dangerous. What happens if `path` is `lib/` and you encouter a sub path `lib/misc/collected/lib/whatever`? While this path males not much sense, it might have been created...)

You return this list from `listfiles()` and then convert them into sets.

If you try to iterate over these sets, you get one path per iteration step.

Answer (score 1):

Your `files_only_x` is a set of *single values*; your `listfiles()` function returns a list of strings, not of tuples with 3 values:

```
for fname in files_only_x:
    print ('\\%s' % fname)
```

Answer (score 1):

You built `files` as a list of strings, therefore the loop in your 2nd code block is wrong as it suggests `files` is list of 3-value tuples.